# Explain theorem in Number theory

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, arithmetic

can some one explain with a clear example this theorem for me,

Let ($A_1$, $A_2$, $A_3$,..., $A_n$) be integars and $p$ a prime number.

if $p|(A_1A_2A_3...A_n)$ then there exist some $1 \leq k \leq N $  such that $p|A_k$.

Then there is a example on this which says,

is 6^100 divisible by 64? answer is yes, why is this? 
64 is not a prime number the theorem says p must be a prime number?

Comment: Counter example :  $$3|111$$

Comment: sorry what do you mean?

Comment: $3$ divides $$1\cdot10^2+10^1\cdot1+10^0\cdot1$$

Comment: @labbhattacharjee I think the statement is that if $p$ divides a product of integers then it divides one of the integers themselves, not that if $p$ divides a number it divides each of the digits.

Comment: where did the plus sign come from I think you have not understood the question
the (A1A2A3...An) is a product I believe Ak is a term in the product

Comment: I've done some formatting, I hope I have interpreted the question correctly.

Comment: By the way, if you know that $p$ prime, $p\mid ab$ implies $p\mid a$ or $p\mid b$, then your question follows by induction on $n$. If you don't know the fact about $p\mid ab$, then, what do you know? What facts about primes are you allowed to use?

Comment: It appears that I was too late editting.

Comment: So far as I can see, the "example" has nothing to do with the theorem.

Comment: well according to my book it does.... 6^100 can be written as (3x2)^100 which also equals 3^100 times 2^100

Comment: Please use more descriptive subjects for your questions, as it stands, interested parties are rather unlikely to find it.

Comment: The theorem plays no role in the example (deducing that $\,(ab)^n\,$ is divisible by $\,a^j b^k\,$  if  $\,j,k\le n)\,$  Which textbook is this from?

Answer (score 1):

This is a rather simple statement that is written in a pretty unclear manner.

What they are saying is that if p is a prime number and $p\vert ab \implies p\vert a$ or $p\vert b$

This can easily be proven with the following proposition:

> If a,b,c are integers with $c\vert ab$ and $gcd(a,c)=1 \implies c\vert b$

As people have said in the comments, the example does not really relate to the theorem at all.